# How to apply transition to fragments using the new Navigation Graph?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have created an animation using `XML` for fade in and out and attached it to the fragment using the drop down in navigation drop for enter and exit but the fragments are not being animated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="com.cheapapps.randomquotesmachine.MainFragment"
    android:label="fragment_main"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_quoteDetailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/quoteDetailFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/quoteDetailFragment"
    android:name="com.cheapapps.randomquotesmachine.QuoteDetailFragment"
    android:label="fragment_quote_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quote_detail">
    <argument
        android:name="position"
        android:defaultValue="0"
        app:argType="integer" />
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `fade_in` and `fade_out` files look like so I'll provide you an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500" />
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="500" />
```

To apply this fade transition to your fragments, you should set `enterAnim` and `exitAnim` as you already did but together with `popEnterAnim` and `popExitAnim` as in the following example:

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_quoteDetailFragment"
    app:destination="@id/quoteDetailFragment"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/fade_out"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/fade_in"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out"/>
```